# How to solve the error while connecting phpmyadmin with PowerBi after installing mysql-connector

Tags: powerbi-desktop, mysql-connector

When I'm try to connect my phpMyAdmin database with PowerBI-Desktop I faced an issue. Then I downloaded MySQL-connector-net(8.1.0). While installing it, it shows 3 options which are change, repair, remove but in Youtube tutorials for solving the error its showing 3 options which are typical, custom and complete. Though the version of MySQL-connector-net they installed is 8.0.32. How can I solve it?[While I'm try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmhLF.png)
[What Youtube tutorial shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp2Ya.png)

After installing the connector it is not working properly though youtube tutorial shows it is enough to connect phpmyadmin with PowerBI-Desktop.